# jQuery, "this", from parent function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build my first Plugin for jQuery and I've the following code. I want to grab a default text, that I did set as $(this).text but it doesn't work this way. I've tried with parent and stuff like that, but without lucky.

Any idea?

Thanks.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.functionName = function( options ) {

  var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.functionName.prototype.defaults, options);
  return this.each(function(){
      // content
  });
};

$.extend( $.fn.functionName.prototype , {

  /** Default Settings **/
  defaults: {
     text: $(this).text(),
     placeholder: false,
     changedColor: "#999",
     hoverColor: false
  },

  replacetags:function(text)
  {
     text = text.replace(/LLEFT/gi,"[");
     text = text.replace(/RRIGHT/gi,"]");
     return text;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Set it to a placeholder value like `null` and in the plugin function check for `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the defaults set outside of the plugin, then you can't use `this` anywhere inside the defaults. I'm only guessing, but were you trying to follow [this plugin pattern](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern)? The big difference is that the options are extended inside of the `// content` area, and that's where you can use `this`.

I'm a bit biased, but I think instead of that pattern, check out the "Namespacing And Nested Namespacing" example in [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/). Essentially, this example:

```
/*!
 * jQuery namespaced 'Starter' plugin boilerplate
 * Author: @dougneiner
 * Further changes: @addyosmani
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

;(function ( $ ) {
    if (!$.myNamespace) {
        $.myNamespace = {};
    };

    $.myNamespace.myPluginName = function ( el, myFunctionParam, options ) {
        // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
        // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
        var base = this;

        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        // Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
        base.$el.data( "myNamespace.myPluginName" , base );

        base.init = function () {
            base.myFunctionParam = myFunctionParam;

            base.options = $.extend({},
            $.myNamespace.myPluginName.defaultOptions, options);

            // Put your initialization code here
        };

        // Sample Function, Uncomment to use
        // base.functionName = function( paramaters ){
        //
        // };
        // Run initializer
        base.init();
    };

    $.myNamespace.myPluginName.defaultOptions = {
        myDefaultValue: ""
    };

    $.fn.mynamespace_myPluginName = function
        ( myFunctionParam, options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            (new $.myNamespace.myPluginName(this,
            myFunctionParam, options));
        });
    };

})( jQuery );
```

You can find this example and a few others in [this github repository](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns/tree/master/patterns)